# PHP MySql Request from outside public_html (Cron Job)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use cron job to make a script that sends scheduled emails to my clients. For more security I will put this PHP file outside public_html folder. I want this file to be a part of my original script So I need to include (mysql_connect.php) in this file so I don't need to connect to database in this file. Is this technically possible?. and How can I call this (mysql_connect.php) file that includes the connection and all my functions that run my original script. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not really make any difference if you're calling it from within public_html or not. You can include the file in the same way. For example say you're setup like this:

`/home/username/myscript.php` and `/home/username/public_html/mysql_connect.php`

Your `myscript.php` file might look something like this:

```
 <? 
     include_once('/home/username/public_html/mysql_connect.php');

     // Your script

 ?>
```

There are better ways to include files than this, e.g. using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but there are plenty of other posts on that.